# Comparing two rates: Poisson test or Fisher test (or logistic regression)

Tags: count-data, fishers-exact-test, methodology, poisson-binomial-distribution

I have a setting in which I want to compare the rate of two count quantities under two different conditions.

This can be achieved in two ways: either using a Poisson test, comparing the cases and using the controls as offset (`T` argument in R `poisson.test()`), or using Fisher's test (or equivalently a logistic regression if data is unaggregated).

The effect size is similar (OR being obviously higher than RR), but statistical significance changes, with Fisher having a slightly lower p value.

Which is the correct approach?

EXAMPLE: Number of treatments for hospital infection on the total number of treatments in two different years:

Fisher test:

```
matrix(c(1715, 1569, 9126 - 1715, 9059 - 1569),byrow = T, ncol = 2) %>% fisher.test() 

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  .
p-value = 0.01034
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.023483 1.192391
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  1.104698
```

Poisson test:

```
poisson.test(c(1715, 1569), c(9126, 9059))

    Comparison of Poisson rates

data:  c(1715, 1569) time base: c(9126, 9059)
count1 = 1715, expected count1 = 1648, p-value = 0.02028
alternative hypothesis: true rate ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.012629 1.162666
sample estimates:
rate ratio 
  1.085028
```

Comment: could you show us an example?  Your question is reasonably clear but might be more accessible with more concrete details